# Zeroclipboard reference error on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, zeroclipboard, referenceerror

I have a ZeroClipboard.js in /vendor/assets/javascripts/. On local desktop, it works perfectly.

On AWS, it gives me the error:

```
GET /assets/ZeroClipboard-04f1243b0e15a4af694be581f7c87be8.js 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard is not defined
```

Why is it not finding ZeroClipboard? It can find, for example, application.js located in /app/assets/javascripts/.

Answer (score 0):

It means the object doesn't exist in S3 (check the path and filename again) or you didn't set up the proper permissions for it. Go to Amazon console, S3 explorer, click the file and edit the permissions so its viewable by all.